# How does CountVectorizer max_features process ngrams with the same frequencies?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I have a question about the CountVectorizer and TfidfVectorizer.

It is unclear to me how the ngrams are selected with the same frequencies in max_features. If we say max_features = 10000 and 100 ngrams in a corpus with the same frequencies on the boarder, how does CountVectorizer separate what ngram will be in the features and what ones will not? The toy example, we have a corpus with eight unique words. Words "jeans" and "cat" have the same freq 1. We take max_features=7. Why "cat" is appear in the features and "jeans" is not, but not vice versa?

```
data = ['gpu processor cpu performance',
        'gpu performance ram computer computer',
        'cpu computer ram processor jeans processor cat']

cv = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features=7)
cv_fit = cv.fit_transform(data).toarray()
cv.vocabulary_

out:
{'cat': 0,
 'computer': 1,
 'cpu': 2,
 'gpu': 3,
 'performance': 4,
 'processor': 5,
 'ram': 6}
```

Answer (score 4):

The CountVectorizer cuts off on term frequency, and might be using normal sort to cut the items at max_features.

> max_features : int or None, default=None If not None, build a
>   vocabulary that only consider the top max_features ordered by term
>   frequency across the corpus.

I changed the data from `cat` to `zat` and now `jeans` makes it to the list.

```
>>> data = ['gpu processor cpu performance',
'gpu performance ram computer computer',
'cpu computer ram processor zat processor jeans']
>>> cv = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features=7)
>>> cv_fit = cv.fit_transform(data).toarray()
>>> cv.vocabulary_
{u'ram': 6, u'jeans': 3, u'processor': 5, u'computer': 0, u'performance': 4, u'gpu': 2, u'cpu': 1}
```

Inherently it is dependent on the sort order.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [link to the relevant source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L734) which occurs in a `_limit_features` helper method:

```
    # Calculate a mask based on document frequencies
    dfs = _document_frequency(X)
    tfs = np.asarray(X.sum(axis=0)).ravel()
    mask = np.ones(len(dfs), dtype=bool)
    if high is not None:
        mask &= dfs <= high
    if low is not None:
        mask &= dfs >= low
    if limit is not None and mask.sum() > limit:
        mask_inds = (-tfs[mask]).argsort()[:limit]
        new_mask = np.zeros(len(dfs), dtype=bool)
        new_mask[np.where(mask)[0][mask_inds]] = True
        mask = new_mask

    new_indices = np.cumsum(mask) - 1  # maps old indices to new
    removed_terms = set()
    for term, old_index in list(six.iteritems(vocabulary)):
        if mask[old_index]:
            vocabulary[term] = new_indices[old_index]
        else:
            del vocabulary[term]
            removed_terms.add(term)
    kept_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
```

Note, `limit` is a parameter of this helper method, which gets passed the value of `self.max_features`. So, as you can see, an array of term-frequencies is calculated:

```
tfs = np.asarray(X.sum(axis=0)).ravel()
```

And the code essentially builds a boolean mask based on the document-frequency values (controlled by the `max_df` and `min_df` values). Then, to limit the mask only to values above `limit`, it does:

```
mask_inds = (-tfs[mask]).argsort()[:limit]
```

Which essentially returns the sorted indices of the term-frequencies array that is sliced to `limit` length with the `[:limit]` slice. Since [`.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) by default uses a quick-sort algorithm, the sort is not stable, and therefore, I believe you can't make many guarantees about *which* term is kept in the case of equal frequencies. It's whatever the quicksort happens to put there. If a stable sorting algorithm were used, (in this case the only one would be merge sort) then since [the vocabulary is first sorted before the `_limit_features` helper function is called](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L874):

```
    if not self.fixed_vocabulary_:
        X = self._sort_features(X, vocabulary)

        n_doc = X.shape[0]
        max_doc_count = (max_df
                         if isinstance(max_df, numbers.Integral)
                         else max_df * n_doc)
        min_doc_count = (min_df
                         if isinstance(min_df, numbers.Integral)
                         else min_df * n_doc)
        if max_doc_count < min_doc_count:
            raise ValueError(
                "max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df")
        X, self.stop_words_ = self._limit_features(X, vocabulary,
                                                   max_doc_count,
                                                   min_doc_count,
                                                   max_features)
```

So the vocabulary would be ordered lexicographically. So, if hypothetically the argsort was using a stable algorithm, I believe we could say that the lexicographically highest term would be kept, however, since it is not stable, we cannot make such a guarantee.